# Android Studio 1.1.0 Expanding Java Folder is not Available

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide

I've faced with and painful issue with Android project view (Android) in Android Studio 1.1.0.

I have a Project that the expanding flesh of java folder is not available anymore, but before then it was available and i was accessing classes through it:

[image: Java Folder Can not Expand]

I will appreciate if someone give it back to me!

Thank You.

Comment: Is the folder structure still intact? if so syncing the project might fix it.

Comment: @Duiker101 Yes it is same as same i even try to invalidate android studio cach and restart it and even syncing but none of them works

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but importing project instead of opening project fix my problem.